# SF2 : Configure a service that gives a new object instance each time

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

By default a symfony 2 service gives a singleton. But in my case, I need a new object instance each time I call my service.

I look at the [symfony 2 tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), the only thing I found is : "we'll learn later how you can configure a service that has multiple instances"...

What is the correct procedure for doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `scope="prototype"`

Comment: `prototype: A new instance is created each time you request the service.`, documented here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html